# Zend Framework Error: Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php'

Tags: php, zend-framework

I get the following error when I try to run the project created by Zend Framework. Its looking for Zend/Application.php and that is available in the directory that is in my include_path. I do have read permissions on the directory.

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [function.require]: 
>   Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' 
>   (include_path='/var/www/vhosts/moderncloud.net/om/library:.:/var/www/vhosts/moderncloud.net/om
>   /library:') in /var/www/vhosts/moderncloud.net/om/public/index.php on
>   line 24

```
<?php


// Define path to application directory
//defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
//    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application');

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));


// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    ('/var/www/vhosts/moderncloud.net/om/library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));


/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

**SOLUTION:**

> I found it myself today. Its a problem with the option
>   "php_admin_value open_basedir" in my httpd configuration. I set it to
>   none and it started working. Alternatively, I guess I can append the Zend library
>   directory to the open_basedir option in my web server configuration instead of setting it to none.

Comment: Can I see what you have in your index.php?

Comment: added index.php to my post. please see above.

Comment: So the full path to the file is `/var/www/vhosts/moderncloud.net/om/library/Zend/Application.php`?

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer yourself, and mark it as the correct answer. That would be more 'correct' than outting it in the question.

Comment: Do you use Zend Framework 2.x? Because it hasn't this file in Library folder. Try install Zend Framework 1.1 and see what will happens

Comment: If new to zend & new project, I strongly suggest using ZF2.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    ('/var/www/vhosts/moderncloud.net/om/library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

with

```
$siteRootDir = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

set_include_path(
    $siteRootDir . '/library' . PATH_SEPARATOR 
    . $siteRootDir . '/application' . PATH_SEPARATOR 
    . get_include_path()
);
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: No. It didn't work for me. I still have the same error. I do have Zend in my library directory and that is readable by my webserver. I also tried giving all permissions on the directory. Still no use.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, remove the existing zend framework installation and install ZF using PEAR. It will be easier to update later on:

```
 pear channel-discover zend.googlecode.com/svn
 pear install zend/zend
```

It will also use PEAR's include_path, so it should solve your problem.

If you can't use pear, try to use relative path with your include path:

```
 // Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

Comment: This didn't work. This is how it was originally and I changed the code and hard-coded the path.

Comment: After Installing Zend using pear (restarted webserver):  [Sun Nov 20 09:41:46 2011] [error] [client 68.228.12.65] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' (include_path=':.:/usr/share/pear:') in /var/www/vhosts/moderncloud.net/om/public/index.php on line 18

Comment: this is strange. try to create a phpinfo.php with <?php phpinfo(); command. check if either safe_mode is turned on, the include_path is wrong, or the php.ini is not loaded

Comment: Safe Mode was turned on. I turned it off. I restarted the web server. No use. I deleted Zend and installed it using Pear. After that the inclue_path has the pear library directory in the path.Still not loading it from there.

Comment: sorry, i can't think about anything else that can be wrong. looks like your environment is set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This problem generated due to :

1. Inside Public folder in index.php file.

or

2. Inside library folder :- Just check in library folder there is a folder of Zend present in library folder or not.If not present zend folder then download from zend framework and save in library folder.

> => In index.php copy the following code and replace it.

```
<?php

 // Define path to application directory

 defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
|| define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/application'));


 // Define application environment
 defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
 || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));  

 // Ensure library/ is on include_path
 set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
 realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
 get_include_path(),
 )));

  /** Zend_Application */
  //require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
  require_once 'library/Zend/Application.php';




  // Create application, bootstrap, and run
 $application = new Zend_Application(
 APPLICATION_ENV,
 APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
      );
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     $application->bootstrap()
        ->run();
```

Comment: This is no different from what I had. But I tried exactly what you said.. No use. Thanks.