# Zend Error ... Browing zend folder showing error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am just new in Zend.

After installing zend i am getting following error. Please any one tell me....

> Zend: Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   'zend_test/Application.php'
>   (include_path='C:\wamp\www\zend_test\library;.;C:\wamp\www\zend_test\library') in C:\wamp\www\zend_test\public\index.php on line 18 Call Stack

Comment: Check if the path is correct.

Comment: [Same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190200/zend-framework-error-failed-opening-required-zend-application-php?rq=1), can't vote as duplicate.

Comment: You are talking about which path?

Comment: If new to zend & new project, I strongly suggest using ZF2.